# Cross-domain tracking Google Analytics and GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pixel, google-tag-manager

I am setting up a website and there's two separate domains. the domains are:

www.exampledomain.se
www.exampledomain.com

I have two separate Google Tag manager containers and two separate Google Analytics accounts. One is connected to each. However the, thank you page after a monetary transaction has been completed is universal and is the same for both pages except the currency that is listed in the url. How can I link this "thank you page" to each domain and only flow the correct data in terms of the currency? Is this possible without any code?

Comment: Just to make sure, the "thank your" page would be on a third domain, and you want CDT between .se and "thank you" / .com and "thank you" respectively, but not between .se and .com. Is that correct ?

Comment: I think he needs a way to decide to wich GA Property the pageview will be send.

Comment: So right now the universal "thank you" page is sending data to a separate property in the GA. Maybe I can just link that Property to the .se and .com properties? That might be the best solution? Agreed?

Comment: I want to be able to see data from the "thank you" page in both the .se and .com property. like the flow charts etc. I can see all flow except the last "thank you" page and that makes it a bit frustrating.

Comment: You might be just using the terminology wrong, but you cannot "link Google Analytics properties" to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tracking the "thankyou" page to a third property you (if I understood correctly) want to click transactions that were initiated by www.exampledomain.se in the GA property for www.exampledomain.se, and similar for the .com domain.

Assuming the confirmation is a single page on a different I would suggest the following:

1. active the built-in referrer variable
2. create a lookup table variable with the referrer as input variable
3. add two rows to the loolup table; if the referrer is the se domain return the tracking id for se, and for com respectively

Your lookup table will look something like this:

[image]

5. Use that lookup table variable in your GA tag instead of a fixed UAID
6. Enter both your domains in the "link domains" field (or create another lookup table to set only the relevant domain, shouldn't really matter)
7. Configure the GA tags in your .se and .com domain for cross domain tracking with the domain for your "thankyou" page

Setting the UAID based on referrer will only work if this is indeed a single page (since on a second page the referrer would no longer point to the external domain).